# Average spectral norm of the random matrix with unit norm rows?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, spectral-theory, spectral-norm

Let $P$ be a distribution of $n \times n$ random matrix whose columns are independent unit norm vectors.

(each rows are drawn uniformly at random from the unit sphere)

Is there any idea about the $\|AB^T\|_2$, where $A, B \sim P$?

I expect it might be $\sqrt{n}$......(it's just my hunch)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?